# Do i really need to call close() for every mongoDB connection instance that i make?

Tags: mongodb

Its my first time to use mongoDB without mongoose. I was just wondering if do i really need to call the close() method everytime i finish a database call? Is there any benefits or security issues if i dont? Thank you!

Comment: No, in fact you shouldn't.

Comment: you shouldn't, recommendation is to use connection pool

Comment: alright so i can just connect, then leave it that way?